# Python Recursion leads to empty list

Tags: python, recursion

We have an input list which can have 4 types of elements (North, East, South, West). We need to remove all consecutive opposite directions to simplify the direction. The trick is that by removing these directions, we create new combinations that we also need to check.

I have already solved it, but now I am trying to do it with a recursive system.

Here's my code :

```
def dirReduc_recu(arr):

  opposite = {"NORTH" : "SOUTH" , "SOUTH" : "NORTH" , "EAST" : "WEST" , "WEST" : "EAST"}
  i = 1 
  
  if len(arr) <= 1 or all(arr[i] != opposite[arr[i+1]] for i in range(len(arr) - 1)):
    return arr 

  last_element = arr[-1]
  avant_dernier_element = arr[-2]

  if last_element == opposite[avant_dernier_element]:
    arr.pop()
    arr.pop()
    dirReduc_recu(arr)
  else : 
    i += 1 
  return dirReduc_recu(arr[:-i])
```

I'm testing this sample:

```
["EAST", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST", "EAST", "EAST", "SOUTH", "NORTH", "WEST"]
```

The result should be:

```
['EAST', 'NORTH']
```

But I get an empty list.

I think the problem is in my base case. In my opinion, the base case should be "Iterate over the list. If you never find any opposite elements, return the list."
I don't know how to translate that into Python code.

Comment: You don't need a recursive solution here – just iterate through the list and restart if you end up erasing an opposite pair...

Comment: The return value of `dirReduc_recu(arr)` is never used. It also passes `arr` by value, and `arr.pop()` will modify that array. `dirReduc_recu(arr[:-i])` on the other hand passes an independent slice, and the `arr.pop()` _won't_ modify any reference to it. Are you aware of this and is that as expected…?

Comment: @AKX No need to restart. Erasing a pair can't create a new pair much earlier in the array.

Comment: @Stef What about something like `["EAST", "EAST", "WEST", "WEST"]`? If we remove the pair at index 1 and 2 we create a new pair at index 0 and 1.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, exactly. In general if you're iterating and you remove a pair at indices (i, i+1) then either it doesn't create a new pair, or it creates a new pair at indices (i-1,i). It cannot create a pair earlier than i-1 in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use recursion for this in python.

Use a while loop with an index `i` in the list, and either increment `i` or remove two elements.

```py
def dirReduc(a):
    i = 0
    while i < ...:
        if tuple(a[i:i+2]) in dirReduc.opposites:
            ...
        else:
            ...
    return a
dirReduc.opposites = {("NORTH","SOUTH"),("SOUTH","NORTH"),...}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your attempt:

- The first recursive call mutates `arr`, but the list that it returns is ignored.
- The second recursive call passes a new list which has fewer values (one or two less), which is also the list that it returns (potentially mutated). This means values have been lost at the end of the list and there is no good reason for it.

Here is a possible way to apply recursion:

```
opposite = {"NORTH" : "SOUTH" , "SOUTH" : "NORTH" , "EAST" : "WEST" , "WEST" : "EAST"}
  
def dirReduc_recu(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return lst
    rest = dirReduc_recu(lst[1:])
    return rest[1:] if rest and lst[0] == opposite[rest[0]] else lst[:1] + rest
```

Here the lists are not mutated; new lists are returned, except for the base case.

For bigger lists, this will be excessive on memory use; it is better to apply recursion on *halves* of the given list and then merge the halves by eliminating any pairs from where they touch:

```
opposite = {"NORTH" : "SOUTH" , "SOUTH" : "NORTH" , "EAST" : "WEST" , "WEST" : "EAST"}
  
def dirReduc_recu(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return lst
    # partition
    mid = len(lst) // 2
    left = dirReduc_recu(lst[:mid])
    right = dirReduc_recu(lst[mid:])
    # merge
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(reversed(left), right)):
        if a != opposite[b]:
            return left[:-i] + right[i:] if i else left + right
    i = min(len(left), len(right))
    return left[:-i] + right[i:]
```